# Android Animation isInitialized returns false sometimes

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am successfully using Android animations but in my current code I call the animations many times and sometimes they do not execute properly. After checking all of my code, I've figured out that the method `isInitialized()` returns `false` sometimes, but I do not know why.

I have tried this way to call animations:

```
Animation anima1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
mView.startAnimation(anima1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the animation directly try to wait to be initialized using the post method of the view

**sample:**

```
Animation anima1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
mView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mView.startAnimation(anima1);

    }
});
```